# How does BlazeDS treats Map inside a Java Bean class?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

//Flex class

```
package com.mycompany{
         import flash.utils.Dictionary;

         [Bindable]
         [RemoteClass(alias="com.mycompany.bean.MessageBundle")]

         [Bindable]
         public class MessageBundleVO{
             public var messages:Object ;

             public function getMessage(key:String):String{
                return messages.key as String;
             }
        }
    }
```

//Java Class

```
package com.mycompany.bean;

        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.Map;

        public class MessageBundle implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private Map messages;

            public Map getMessageBundle() {
                return messages;
            }

            public void setMessageBundle(Map messageBundle) {
                this.messages = messageBundle;
            }

            public String toString(){
                return messages.toString();
            }
        }
```

Everything is properly linked and instance for MessageBundleVO is not null but the its attribute messages is coming null.

Can you please tell me what is the Flex equivalent of Map if we use RemoteClass tag as give in the above code.

This is comming null on the flex side.
        MessageBundleVO.messages

```
    The Aodbe
    http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html

    is suggesting
    Array (sparse)—->java.util.Map–>java.util.Map
```

Answer (score 1):

Many things here :

- Variable name: BlazeDS uses public fields and public accessors as serialized variable names. So from the flex point of view, MessageBundle java class contains only a map called "messageBundle", and nothing called "messages"
- It will be converted as an object, so this is ok
- In your getMessage function client side, I don't think the function will do what you think it will do :). In the current version, it will fetch the property named "key". To achieve what you need, you should replace "messages.key" by "messages[key]"
- You don't need to have 2 times the [Bindable] metadata